# Difference of n/=10 and n=n/10

Tags: c, microcontroller

is there any difference between `n/=10` and `n=n/10` in execution speed wise?

just like `n--` and `--n` are differ in their execution speed wise also...

Comment: No, there's no difference between them besides for compiling

Comment: `n/=10` theoretically doesn't create a temporary, while `n=n/10` theoretically does, but in practice it would be optimised by the compiler anyway.

Comment: If in doubt, let the compiler create an assembler listing of both variants and compare them

Comment: Indeed, the difference in execution speed between n/=10 and n=n/10 is (almost certainly) the same as the difference between --n and n--

Comment: @WilliamPursell i guess modern compilers generate same assembly for n-- and --n if they are between two sequence points?and so should for n/=10 and n=n/10?

Comment: On my system (gcc 4.6.3) both produce the same binary.

Comment: then its always better to use n/=10, cause speed is one of the most important factor in controller... @WilliamPursell

Comment: Only non-orthogonal CPU architectures are likely to have a timing difference between `--n` and `n--`.  Which microcontroller is being used?

Answer (score 5):

**No, not really:**

> `[C99: 6.5.16.2/3]:` A compound assignment of the form `E1 op= E2` differs from the simple assignment expression `E1 = E1 op (E2)` only in that the lvalue `E1` is evaluated only once.

So, this has consequences only if your `n` is a non-trivial expression with side-effects (such as a function call).

Otherwise, I suppose in theory an intermediate temporary variable will be involved, but you'd have to be remarkably unlucky for such a temporary to actually survive in your compiled executable. You're not going to see any performance difference between the two approaches.

Confirm this with benchmarks, and by comparing the resulting assembly.

Comment: Unless, of course, `n` is `volatile`, in which case otherwise possible optimizations will be suppressed.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze: I don't see why. The standard guarantees the behaviour of the compound operation, as described above.

Comment: In C11, this text was modified to also say that, for the compound operator only, an indeterminately-sequenced function call cannot occur in between the computation of `n / 10` and the assignment back to `n`; and also to define the behaviour for atomics.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following C-code:

```
int f1(int n) {
   n /= 10;
   return n;
}

int f2(int n) {
   n = n / 10;
   return n;
}
```

compiled with `gcc -O4` essentially results in

```
f1:
        movl    %edi, %eax
        movl    $1717986919, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edi
        imull   %edx
        sarl    $2, %edx
        subl    %edi, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        ret

f2:
        movl    %edi, %eax
        movl    $1717986919, %edx
        sarl    $31, %edi
        imull   %edx
        sarl    $2, %edx
        subl    %edi, %edx
        movl    %edx, %eax
        ret
```

I have omitted some boilerplate which is part of the listing in reality.

**In this specific case, there is no difference between the two alternatives.**

Depending on the compiler used, on the actual environment where the instructions are executed and on compiler optimization levels, the generated code might be different. But you can always use this approach to check if the resulting machine code differs or not.

Comment: Try `int f1(int nn) { volatile int n = nn; n /= 10; return n; }` and `int f1(int nn) { volatile int n = nn; n = n / 10; return n; }`. That may make a difference.

Comment: No, it adds some `movl` instructions, but is again the same in both cases ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference b/w the both.

Answer (score -2):

I have checked it in the KEIL cross compiler for both expressions and same execution time required:

```
=================================================
     5: x=x/5; 
     6:  
C:0x0005    EF       **MOV      A,R7**

C:0x0006    75F005   **MOV      B(0xF0),#0x05**

C:0x0009    84       **DIV      AB**

     7: x/=5; 

C:0x000A    75F005   **MOV      B(0xF0),#0x05**

C:0x000D    84       **DIV      AB**

C:0x000E    FF       **MOV      R7,A**

================================================
```

So, there is no any difference, like with `--n` and `n--`.

Comment: There are infinitely many possible C implementations and infinitely many C programs that contain this source code. Testing a program on one C implementation tells you only about one C implementation with one program. In contrast, the rules of C tell you about all C implementations. Unless the question is specifically restricted to a single situation, it cannot be answered with a single test.